# Sequence contains more than one matching element Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have mvc 5 and ef 6 project

In my repository i have code snippets for get all job in my database

```
 public List<Job> GetAllJob()
        {

            if (_job.Any())
            {
                var r = (from j in _job where j.JobStatus == 1 select j).ToList();
                return r;
                //return _job.Where(j => j.JobStatus==1).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

execution time, When the compiler arrives to Any() method get me this error:

**Sequence contains more than one matching element**

[image: Details Error]

System.InvalidOperationException:

```
{System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one matching element
```

StackTrace:

```
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.<>c__DisplayClass24f.<FindAlteredColumns>b__246(<>f__AnonymousType2b`2 <>h__TransparentIdentifier241)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(ModelMetadata source, ModelMetadata target, Lazy`1 modificationCommandTreeGenerator, MigrationSqlGenerator migrationSqlGenerator, String sourceModelVersion, String targetModelVersion)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, Lazy`1 modificationCommandTreeGenerator, MigrationSqlGenerator migrationSqlGenerator, String sourceModelVersion, String targetModelVersion)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.IsModelOutOfDate(XDocument model, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__e()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Any[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at ServiceLayer.JobService.GetAllJob() in C:\Users\MRT\Desktop\Final\MapWeb - Copy\ServiceLayer\JobService.cs:line 33
   at WebMap.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in C:\Users\MRT\Desktop\Final\MapWeb - Copy\WebMap\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 25
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
```

migration history table:

[image: migration history table]

and this is Job DomainClasse:

```
 public partial class Job
    {
        //[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        //public Job()
        //{
        //    Channels = new Channel();
        //    Products = new HashSet<Product>();
        //}

        public long JobId { get; set; }

        public long UserId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]


        public string JobName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(150)]

        public string JobDescripton { get; set; }
        [Index("IX_Jobs", order: 2)]
        public long JobCategoryId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(500)]


        public string JobAddress { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(10)]


        public string JobPhone { get; set; }

        [StringLength(500)]


        public string JobImgUrl { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime JobTimeRegister { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string JobLogLat { get; set; }

        public byte JobStatus { get; set; }
        [Index("IX_Jobs",order:1)]


        public int ShahrestanId { get; set; }
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public long ChannelId { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual Channel Channels { get; set; }

        public virtual JobCategory JobCategory { get; set; }

        public virtual Tbl_Shahrestan Tbl_Shahrestan { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
```

dbContext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Job>()
                .HasOptional(e => e.Channels)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Job)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Job>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Products)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Job)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

It is interesting to know  Whenever execute Entityframework commands (Specifically update-database , add-migration) Get me an Error:

***Sequence contains more than one matching element***

I have no idea Why get me this error

----update add JobService for singleOrDefault Querys----

```
namespace ServiceLayer
{
    public class JobService : IJobService
    {
        private IUnitOfWork _uow;
        private IDbSet<Job> _job;
        private IUserService _userService;


        public JobService(IUnitOfWork uow, IUserService userService)
        {
            _uow = uow;
            _userService = userService;
            _job = _uow.Set<Job>();
        }


        public List<Job> GetAllJob()
        {

            if (_job.Any())
            {
                var r = (from j in _job where j.JobStatus == 1 select j).ToList();
                return r;
                //return _job.Where(j => j.JobStatus==1).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public List<Job> GetAllJobsOneUser(string username)
        {
            User user = _userService.GetCurrentUser(username);
            List<Job> jobs = (from j in _job where j.User.UserId == user.UserId select j).ToList();
            _userService.GetOneUserAndEnCryptData(user);
            _uow.MarkAsChanged(user);
            return jobs;
        }

        public Job GetOneJobOneUser(long? jobId, string username)
        {
            if (jobId == null || jobId <= 0)
                return null;
            User user = _userService.GetCurrentUser(username);
            Job job = (from j in _job where j.User.UserId == user.UserId && j.JobId == jobId select j).SingleOrDefault();
            _userService.GetOneUserAndEnCryptData(user);
            _uow.MarkAsChanged(user);

            return job ;
        }

        public bool AddOneJobOneUser(Job job, HttpPostedFileBase JobImgUrl, string username)
        {
            User user = _userService.GetCurrentUser(username);
            job.JobStatus = (byte)ConfirmationStatus.Pending;
            job.UserId = user.UserId;
            job.JobTimeRegister = DateTime.Now;

            if (JobImgUrl != null) 
            {


                if (JobImgUrl.ContentLength > 51200000) 
                {

                    //return View();
                    return false;
                }
                if (JobImgUrl.ContentType != "image/jpeg") 
                {


                    return false;
                }

                Random rnd = new Random();
                string RndImageFileName = rnd.Next().ToString() + ".jpg";

                JobImgUrl.SaveAs(Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + "Upload/Imgs/Job/" + RndImageFileName));

                job.JobImgUrl = RndImageFileName; 
            }
            _job.Add(job);
            _userService.GetOneUserAndEnCryptData(user);
            _uow.MarkAsChanged(user);
            return true;
        }

        public bool EditOneJobOneUser(string username, Job job, HttpPostedFile ProductImageUrl)
        {
            try
            {

                var q = GetOneJobOneUser(job.JobId, username);
                if (q != null)
                {

                    if (ProductImageUrl != null)
                    {

                        if (System.IO.File.Exists(Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + "Upload/Imgs/Job/" +job.JobImgUrl)))

                        {
                            System.IO.File.Delete(Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + "Upload/Imgs/Job/" +job.JobImgUrl));
                        }
                        Random rnd = new Random();

                        q.JobImgUrl = rnd.Next().ToString() + ".jpg";
                        ProductImageUrl.SaveAs(Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + "Upload/Imgs/Product/" + q.JobImgUrl));

                    }
                    q.JobStatus = (byte) ConfirmationStatus.Pending;
                    q.JobTimeRegister = DateTime.Now;
                    q.ShahrestanId = job.ShahrestanId;
                }

                User user = _userService.GetCurrentUser(username);

                if (q.UserId == user.UserId)
                {
                    _job.Attach(q);
                    _uow.MarkAsChanged(q);
                    _userService.GetOneUserAndEnCryptData(user);
                    _uow.MarkAsChanged(user);
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    _userService.GetOneUserAndEnCryptData(user);
                    _uow.MarkAsChanged(user);
                    return false;
                }


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var str = e.Message;
                return false;
            }
        }

        public bool RemoveOneJobOneUser(long? jobId,string username)
        {
            if (jobId == null || jobId <= 0)
                return false;
            try
            {
            Job job = (from j in _job where  j.User.Mobile == username && j.JobId == jobId  select j).SingleOrDefault(); 

            if (job == null)
                return false;

                _job.Remove(job);
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {

                return false;
            }



        }

        public Job GetOneJobOneUser(long userId, long jobId)
        {
            return (from j in _job where j.JobId == jobId && j.User.UserId == userId select j).SingleOrDefault();
        }

        public Job GetOneActiveJob(long? jobId)
        {
            if (jobId == null || jobId <= 0)
                return null;
            return (from j in _job where j.JobStatus.Equals(1) && j.JobId==jobId select j).FirstOrDefault();
        }


        public bool CheckJobExist(string username)
        {
            List<Job> existJob=GetAllJobsOneUser(username);
            if (existJob == null)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
    }
}
```

but when i change singleOrDefualt to FirstOrDefault still get me error

Comment: Could be something odd with migrations, the stack traces seem to indicate that. Could you maybe show the contents of your migration history table?

Comment: You haven't shown the query `_jobs`. I guess it contains a `SingleOrDefault` call but the query returned more than one row.

Comment: _job can be null ?

Comment: What is `_job`?

Comment: @juunas i update orginal post and add new pic f migration history table .

Comment: @TimSchmelter i change All SingleOrDefault To FirstOrDefault but get me this error.

Comment: @ poke  _job is db.job on UnitOfWork

Comment: @HüseyinBurakKaradag yes _job is table like db.job

Comment: Try changing `[Column(TypeName = "date")]` attribute into `[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]` and redo migration again.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto i changed but still say : Sequence contains more than one matching element

Comment: I can see at least 3 duplicate migrations in the history table. That would definitely cause it to crash. Haven't really had such situations before, and am not sure if you can fix that by just fiddling with the history table.

Comment: I'm not sure if multiple column index attribute with `[Index("IX_Jobs",order:n)]` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#Index) causing matching element error, but `ColumnAttribute` often triggers it. Try changing to `[Index("IX_Jobs", n)]` or remove them.

Comment: @juunas name are same but last of names have number

Comment: How about "removeSaltStringLength"? It's in there twice even though you only have one file.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Not different

Comment: @juunas  The point is I have deleted some migration files ,i took a right pic in db.migration watch it https://ibb.co/k1RvFa , delete old migration file and migation table ?

Comment: Guys i have a question : Can i use () Configure relationship using DataAnnotations an using Fluent API together ? I mean is ex : Definition a pk or fk in dataAnntations and in fluent api too .